# Download JDK7 Select a JDK from the File System Open build.gradle

Tags: android, java, gradle

`build.gradle`ファイルに`compileSdkVersion 23`と記述されており、AndroidStudioが`Download JDK7 Select a JDK from the File System Open build.gradle`というエラーメッセージを出します。

現在、Macに入っているJavaは下記のようにJava8です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[Java SE Development Kit 7 - Downloads | Oracle Technology Network | Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)
からJava7をダウンロードしてくればよいと思うのですが、Java7をインストールした場合、現状のJava8はどうなるのでしょうか？　セキュリティの観点から最新のJavaをMacで使用した方がよいと考えているので、Java7にダウングレードするのはよくないと考えています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compileSdkVersion は AndroidSDKのバージョン
Android Studioに必要なのはJDK
JDKは異なるバージョンを共存可能
添付の画像は現在macで使用しているJREのバージョン
エラーメッセージはAndroid StudioにJDKの場所が設定されていないときに表示される
最新のAndroid StudioはJDK8を使用可能

取り急ぎ

Comment: なるほど。File > Project Structure　の設定が`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`になっていたところ`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home`に変更したところ、エラーがなくなりました。